# JSP sessions while on Tor

Tags: tor

How do login sessions work while on Tor, since Tor browser disables cookies? Always has confused me how the site can differentiate users.

I know there are additional ways other than cookies, but still none the wiser how they work while on Tor.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Tor Browser forces cookies to be discarded at the end of the browsing session. Cookies are small pieces of data that websites use to keep notes on who you are. They are commonly used as a login token, or as an identifier for adveritsment companies to track you across multiple sites. By discarding all cookies when you start a new browsing session, these cannot be used to track you across sites.Tor Browser disables the Flash plugin, which has its own form of persistent storage. As Flash applets auto-load on most systems, this again prevents a method of tracking you across sessions.A similar story applies for HTML5 storage capability. Websites can store data on your machine with the use of HTML5. This data can be much larger and more varied than cookies, and is technically distinct; but the risks in terms of being used as a tracking mechanism are the same.

Comment: When you say "end of browsing session" this would be when user exits page or clicks the logout button, correct? If I understood: cookies are used, but then discarded, no different to any other website?

Comment: Yes but it disregards all cookies between sessions. To my understanding i think it just throws all the cookies in the trash once the connection with the specific site is terminated. Tell me if you need anything else! If my answer was good and help you understand please do press the little tick under the score and/or the up vote!

Comment: Thanks, I did it. You might not see it until I get 15 rep.  Mind checking out this other thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452458/jsp-spring-mvc-tor

Comment: got no clue about that.Btw you haven't accepted the answer. Accepting it is by pressing the green thingy under the two arrows :) Good day

Answer (score 0):

The first part answers the question: "Actually Tor Browser forces cookies to be discarded at the end of the browsing session." So cookies are used like any normal website until you finish the session, then they are deleted.

Actually Tor Browser forces cookies to be discarded at the end of the browsing session. Cookies are small pieces of data that websites use to keep notes on who you are. They are commonly used as a login token, or as an identifier for adveritsment companies to track you across multiple sites. By discarding all cookies when you start a new browsing session, these cannot be used to track you across sites.Tor Browser disables the Flash plugin, which has its own form of persistent storage. As Flash applets auto-load on most systems, this again prevents a method of tracking you across sessions.A similar story applies for HTML5 storage capability. Websites can store data on your machine with the use of HTML5. This data can be much larger and more varied than cookies, and is technically distinct; but the risks in terms of being used as a tracking mechanism are the same.